# phpMyAdmin MySQL error # 1045

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, wamp

I have been working on setting up a home web server all morning now and it is working great except the fact that I can no longer access phpMyAdmin from the web server. The password and user in config.inc.php match the password in MySQL, I can access the MySQL Console fine.

I have set up port forwarding for the web server, registered a domain name with a DNS, and modified the httpd.conf file to allow access.

Here is the httpd.conf directory portions:

```xml
ServerName localhost:80
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

And here is my config.inc.php file:

```
<?php

/* Servers configuration */
$i = 0;

/* Server: localhost [1] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'XXXXXXX';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

/* End of servers configuration */

$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en-utf-8';
$cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';


/* rajk - for blobstreaming */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_garbage_threshold'] = 50;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_repository_threshold'] = '32M';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_temp_blob_timeout'] = 600;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_temp_log_threshold'] = '32M';
?>
```

I have read hours and hours of questions and answers, I have no idea what is causing this, any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was.
While all my above information is correct the web browser cached the information when it was incorrect. All I had to do was clear the cache and restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

For me after searching in many answers was changing host in config.inc.php.

By default it is:

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';

But changing to

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';

solved problem for me.